# Real data elements from JSON

Tags: python, json, web-crawler

I am trying to extract data elements from json url link using python.Below is the code. It is working partially when I try to extract elements

> ```
>  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>     data = json.loads(response.read())
>     print("planId",data[0]["planId"]) #Gives result as planId PWR93173MBE1
>     print("postcode",data[0]["postcode"]) # Gives result as postcode 2000
>     print("tariffType", data[0]["tariffType"]) This gives me error.
> ```

Also, if I want to extract other elements such as PlanType and other fields in Fees, how can I do it?

```
   [
       {
          "planData":{
             "planType":"M",
             "tariffType":"SR",
             "contract":[
                {
                   "pricingModel":"SR",
                   "benefitPeriod":"Ongoing",
                   "coolingOffDays":10,
                   "additionalFeeInformation":"This offer provides access to wholesale prices, utilises your Powerbank to smooth wholesale market volatility and Powerwatch to warn of higher prices. For more information on this and any other standard fees, visit our website www.powerclub.com.au",
                   "fee":[
                      {
                         "description":"Annual Membership payable each year for each of your business premises taking supply.",
                         "amount":79,
                         "feeType":"MBSF",
                         "percent":0,
                         "feeTerm":"A"
                      },
                      {
                         "description":"Cost for providing a paper bill",
                         "amount":2.5,
                         "feeType":"PBF",
                         "percent":0,
                         "feeTerm":"F"
                      },
                      {
                         "description":"Disconnection fee",
                         "amount":59.08,
                         "feeType":"DiscoF",
                         "percent":0,
                         "feeTerm":"F"
                      },
                      {
                         "description":"Reconnection Fee",
                         "amount":59.08,
                         "feeType":"RecoF",
                         "percent":0,
                         "feeTerm":"F"
                      },
                      {
                         "description":"Meter  Read - Requested by  Customer",
                         "amount":12.55,
                         "feeType":"OF",
                         "percent":0,
                         "feeTerm":"F"
                      }
                   ],
          "planId":"PWR93173MBE1",
          "planType":"E#B#PWR93173MBE1",
          "postcode":2000
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problems you're running into, desired result and what's what you need to get extracted from fees?

Comment: From fees I want description and amount.  I tried to get description print("Fees", data[0]['planData']['fee']['description']) but it does not work. Hope I was able to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tariffType` property sits inside the `planData` property, so you need to do something like

```
print("tariffType", data[0]["planData"]["tariffType"])
```

Comment: I tried to follow the same and am trying to get fee and I tried print("Fees", data[0]['planData']['fee']['description'])  and print("Fees", data[0]['fee']) , but it does not work. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Again, that `fee` property is nested lower down the tree. You need `data[0]['planData']['contract'][0]['fee']` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to nest, correct should be:

```py
print("tariffType", data[0]["planData"]["tariffType"])
```